# Ancient Greek hyphenation in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, babel, greek

Can anybody tell me the current state of hyphenation patterns in LuaLaTeX, especially with regard to Ancient Greek?

I searched here on tex.sx and on the web. There are many mailing lists discussing particular problems, but all is very scattered. There is also some documentation on CTAN for `hyph-utf8` but it lacks information for LuaLaTeX (or I missed this bit).

So, what should I do if I want to typeset Ancient Greek *and* want to have the text properly hyphenated? Or should I wait for further developments?

Comment: lualtex reads the same hyphenation pattern syntax as latex, my texlive 2012 has % File name: hyph-grc.tex
%
% Created:       June 6, 2008
% Last modified: Sept. 12, 2011
%
% Unicode hyphenation patterns for Ancient Greek.
%   which would seem to be what you need?

Comment: yes it is, but I did not know how to employ it.

Comment: Looks like @egreg sorted it out, I suppose I'll have to vote for him:-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made this experiment. It's necessary to kill the action of `\greektext` in order to avoid setting the font encoding to LGR.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}

\let\greektext\relax

% very narrow columns!
\columnsep=2cm
\textwidth=\dimexpr7\columnsep+8pt\relax
\hfuzz=\maxdimen % no overfull \hbox message

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{8}
\noindent\hspace{0pt}%
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,
πολλὰς δ᾽ ἰφθίμους ψυχὰς Ἄϊδι προΐαψεν
ἡρώων, αὐτοὺς δὲ ἑλώρια τεῦχε κύνεσσιν
οἰωνοῖσί τε πᾶσι, Διὸς δ᾽ ἐτελείετο βουλή,
ἐξ οὗ δὴ τὰ πρῶτα διαστήτην ἐρίσαντε
Ἀτρεΐδης τε ἄναξ ἀνδρῶν καὶ δῖος Ἀχιλλεύς.
τίς τ᾽ ἄρ σφωε θεῶν ἔριδι ξυνέηκε μάχεσθαι;
Λητοῦς καὶ Διὸς υἱός: ὃ γὰρ βασιλῆϊ χολωθεὶς
νοῦσον ἀνὰ στρατὸν ὄρσε κακήν, ὀλέκοντο δὲ λαοί,
οὕνεκα τὸν Χρύσην ἠτίμασεν ἀρητῆρα
Ἀτρεΐδης: ὃ γὰρ ἦλθε θοὰς ἐπὶ νῆας Ἀχαιῶν
λυσόμενός τε θύγατρα φέρων τ᾽ ἀπερείσι᾽ ἄποινα,
στέμματ᾽ ἔχων ἐν χερσὶν ἑκηβόλου Ἀπόλλωνος
χρυσέῳ ἀνὰ σκήπτρῳ, καὶ λίσσετο πάντας Ἀχαιούς,
Ἀτρεΐδα δὲ μάλιστα δύω, κοσμήτορε λαῶν:
Ἀτρεΐδαι τε καὶ ἄλλοι ἐϋκνήμιδες Ἀχαιοί,
ὑμῖν μὲν θεοὶ δοῖεν Ὀλύμπια δώματ᾽ ἔχοντες
ἐκπέρσαι Πριάμοιο πόλιν, εὖ δ᾽ οἴκαδ᾽ ἱκέσθαι:
παῖδα δ᾽ ἐμοὶ λύσαιτε φίλην, τὰ δ᾽ ἄποινα δέχεσθαι,
ἁζόμενοι Διὸς υἱὸν ἑκηβόλον Ἀπόλλωνα.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The words are hyphenated at all feasible points, you can check if the hyphenation is correct.

[image]

### Added December 2013

The `babel-greek` package has undergone several modifications. Now the correct way to call `polutoniko` and `babel` with XeLaTeX is to load `babel` *after* `fontspec`, so that the correct font encoding is guessed. There's apparently no need to kill `\greektext` any more.

I'll report only the first lines of the corrected example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Old Standard}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}

% very narrow columns!
\columnsep=2cm
\textwidth=\dimexpr7\columnsep+8pt\relax
\hfuzz=\maxdimen % no overfull \hbox message

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{8}
\noindent\hspace{0pt}%
μῆνιν ἄειδε θεὰ Πηληϊάδεω Ἀχιλῆος
οὐλομένην, ἣ μυρί᾽ Ἀχαιοῖς ἄλγε᾽ ἔθηκε,

...
```

The output should be the same as before.

Comment: Yes, good idea to use `\let\greektext\relax`. I tried `polutonikogreek` before, but of course with messy results. Does this mean that babel reliably and by itself employs the hyphenation patterns mentioned by David?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I get the same language (hyphenation pattern set) as it is chosen when using `pdflatex` with the `polutonikogreek` option to `babel`

Comment: Any changes in TeXLive 2013? I get an error message when bable tries to load `polutonikogreek`, for example: `...babel-greek/greek.ldf:74: String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. l.74 \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\"}{LGR}{ü}{\accdialytika}`.

Comment: @ClintEastwood The example compiles in the same way with TeX Live 2013

Comment: no, not on my laptop. I just updated mactex, but still the same issue. I think the `babel-greek` files are saved with the wrong encoding. I just opened it and it was in `MacRoman`

Comment: @ClintEastwood Yes, a recent update to `greek.ldf` broke the usage with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121842/polutoniko-greek-in-texlive-2013

Comment: Your work on this site is amazing. I hope I have not been not bugging you in the last weeks. I am commenting now to ask about `polutonikogreek` again. It seems to have been changed (again) to the effect that it does not work anymore. Not even the example in your own answer here compiles properly. Any ideas what happened?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Now it should work