# Polutoniko Greek in TexLive 2013

Tags: texlive, babel, greek

I can no longer compile files with the polutonikogreek language option to babel in TexLive 2013. Everything was fine in TL2012. There is another question showing the same problem: [Ancient Greek hyphenation in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112905/ancient-greek-hyphenation-in-lualatex) but the solution given there does nto work for me. In fact, the minimal example given in the answer does not compile on my system.
I just upgraded to TL2013 from TL2012 and asked the installer to bring over my old settings from TL2012. Perhaps that's the problem?

Help appreciated.

EDIT: Problem has been fixed by babel-greek maintainer in version 1.5a

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @stefano : There seems to be a new problem. Since a few days, I can no longer compile. Are you uptodate with your distribution? Do you experience errors as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `greek.ldf` 2013/05/17 v1.4

The example file in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112939/16967) in [question "Ancient Greek hyphenation in LuaLaTeX"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112905/16967) breaks with `greek.ldf` 2013/05/17 v1.4 with LuaLaTeX
because of 8-bit characters:

```
l.74 \DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\"}{LGR}{
                                         �}{\accdialytika}
? 
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
```

Using `^^`-notation instead of the 8-bit characters might fix the issue.

**Update:** I have reported it as bug [`babel/4303`](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=babel/4303).

### Fix suggestion

The five lines with the 8-bit byte encoded in `^^`-notation:

```
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\"}{LGR}{^^9f}{\accdialytika}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{LGR}{^^9f}{\@hiatus}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\`}{LGR}{^^9f}{\@hiatus}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\<}{LGR}{^^9f}{\@hiatus}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\>}{LGR}{^^9f}{\@hiatus}
```

However, it depends, how `greek.ldf` was unpacked. It depends on the TeX compiler and its options, whether the 8-bit characters of the `.dtx` file are passed through as 8-bit characters or whether the TeX compiler converts them to the `^^`-notation.

### `greek.ldf` 2013/06/21 v1.5

This version additionally breaks with a different error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\greek@attr@polutoniko ...{\extraspolutonikogreek
```

Thus I made a new bug report [babel/4305](http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?pr=babel/4305).

Comment: It breaks also with version 1.5 recently uploaded.

Comment: Heiko,  thanks for the quick answer, but I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by ^^-notation. A Google search did not bring up anything.

Comment: @stefano: See [TeX by Topic, section "2.6 Accessing the full character set"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf) or this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64848/16967).

Comment: @Heiko: thanks for the pointers. I read both and now know a bit more about ^^xy notation. But as this stuff is still way over my head, could you (or anyone else more conversant with (Lua)TeX internals than me) confirm the following: (1) the problem is in those 4 lines (94-97) in greek.ldf that use 8 bit characters. (2) The problem could be solved (at least for LuaTeX) by replacing the troublesome characters with their appropriate equivalents in ^^-notation. If (1) and (2) are true, then the obvious question is: what are the hex code of those characters?

Comment: @stefano No, the problem is not solvable by changing the explicit `0x9F` characters into `^^9f`, because this combination is illegal in UTF-8. It has to do with accents inside `\MakeUppercase`. However, this shouldn't be needed with Unicode engines such as XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the clarification. Rolling back to Tl2012 as we speak...

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I tried the same fix, but LuaLaTeX still balks.

Comment: @egreg: For `greek.ldf` v1.4 the fix worked for me. In `greek.ldf` v1.5 this is also fixed in this way. But I got a different error about undefined `\extraspolutonikogreek`.

Comment: On my system, version 1.5 still has the same `0x9F` character, not `^^9f`; if I try to change it to `^^9f` the problem remains (malformed UTF-8 sequence).

Comment: @egreg: I had tried with a fresh copy from CTAN and had used `tex greek.ins` to unpack the files. That had automatically replaced the 8-bit characters to `^^9f`.

Comment: @egreg imho changing to ^^9f should not give an illegal utf8-message as ^^9f is not interpreted as a byte sequence but as an unicode code point - at least I know from an old discussion that's how xetex is interpreting this. E.g. ^^a2 will give "CENT SIGN". ^^9f is naturally the wrong code point for the accent with luatex but this shouldn't matter much as LGR encoding shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: @Heiko: same here. If I change the codes to ^^9F in greek.ldf compilation of the test file stops on: \greek@attr@polutoniko ...{\extraspolutonikogreek 
                                                  }\let \captionsgreek \capt...
l.293 \ProcessOptions*