# \endcsname error with nag and newest babel/greek update

Tags: errors, babel, greek, nag

Did I miss something with `babel` and `polutonikogreek`? I just updated my TeX distribution on my mac through TeX Live Utility, and now I get the error:

```
./document.tex:5: Missing \endcsname inserted.
 <to be read again> 
 \protect 
 l.5 \begin{document}
```

This is the file:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

---

**Update**: The result is that even without `nag` (as egreg pointed out in his answer) the `polutonikogreek`-option of `babel` (which I need for [hyphenation of Ancient Greek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112905/12277)) does no longer work.

Comment: My crystal ball went into strike after seeing this; even crystal balls have their limits and working rights. `;-)`

Comment: I do regular updates and have not seen anything like that. Without a MWE it's really impossible to tell anything sensible. Have you tried removing the auxiliary files?

Comment: @egreg : I know. Sorry. Auxiliary files is the first thing I do when encountering a new error. Now I digged deeper and updatad the question with an MWE.

Comment: The error is due to `nag`. I see no reason for using it.

Comment: @egreg : but only in connection to `polutonikogreek`, as it seems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is in `nag` that wants to use expandably `\roman`, which it isn't when the Greek module for `babel` is used.

You can fix it with

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}
\makeatletter
% original is \renewcommand\thenag@c{\roman{nag@c}}
\renewcommand\thenag@c{\romannumeral\c@nag@c}
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,british]{babel}
\begin{document}
    test
\end{document}
```

Note that similar errors will happen for `lipsum`, which relies on `\roman` being fully expandable.

Comment: Without using `nag` I now get quite a few errors in many of the lines which contain Greek. I guess something in the Greek parts of babel (or somewhere else) may have been changed, which then caused my initial error and the new ones now.

Comment: @ClintEastwood `babel-greek` has been deeply modified in recent times. Without an example it's impossible to say something more. But it should be a different question.

Comment: This solution works for me, only when I place the code `\renewcommand` part of the code before I include the babel package. I babel comes first, then I get the same error as posted in the question.

Comment: @DohnJoe Yes, you're supposed to place the code *before* `\documentclass` as shown in the example.

Comment: I placed it in the preamble before the inclusion of babel. Usually the `\documentclass` is the first line of code. What things have to be put before `\documentclass`?

Comment: @DohnJoe The `nag` package should be called *before* `\documentclass` for full functionality, with `\RequirePackage`; then the faulty code in it must be redefined, all before `\documentclass`.