# Does polyglossia with LuaLaTeX hyphenate greek text?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia, greek

Is there a way to tell `polyglossia` to hyphenate a Greek text when run with `LuaLaTeX`? I tried quite a lot (`greek` as `defaultlanguage`, as `backgroundlanguage`, as `otherlanguage`, with german, with english, with this and that font, `\let\greektext\relax` ...), but whatever I do, it doesn't hyphenate. Sometimes `LuaLaTeX` hyphenates with `babel` and `XeLaTeX` hyphenates with nearly the same `usepackages`, though the gets somewhat bolder and fuzzy under `XeLaTeX` (why???), so I prefer `LuaLaTeX`. The answers to similar question in this forum don't help me at all.

The most miminimal WE looks like this:

```
% -*- mode: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
  \begin{document}
      ΣΩ.\quad Οὑτωσὶ τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ καλέ, ἐννόησον, ὡς ὁ μὲν πρότερος ἦν λόγος Φαίδρου τοῦ Πυθοκλέους, Μυρρινουσίου ἀνδρός· ὃν δὲ μέλλω λέγειν Στησιχόρου τοῦ Εὐφήμου, Ἱμεραίου. λεκτέος δὲ ὧδε, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστ’\,ἔτυμος λόγος ὃς ἂν παρόντος ἐραστοῦ τῷ μὴ ἐρῶντι φῇ δεῖν χαρίζεσθαι, διότι δὴ ὁ μὲν μαίνεται, ὁ δὲ σωφρονεῖ. εἰ μὲν γὰρ ἦν ἁπλοῦν τὸ μανίαν κακὸν εἶναι, καλῶς ἂν ἐλέγετο· νῦν δὲ τὰ μέγιστα τῶν ἀγαθῶν ἡμῖν γίγνεται διὰ μανίας θείᾳ μέντοι δόσει διδομένης.

      Ἥ τε γὰρ ἐν ∆ελφοῖς προφῆτις αἵ τ’\,ἐν ∆ωδώνῃ ἱέρειαι μανεῖσαι μὲν πολλὰ δὴ καὶ καλὰ ἰδίᾳ τε καὶ δημοσίᾳ τὴν Ἑλλάδα ἠργάσαντο, σωφρονοῦσαι δὲ βραχέα ἢ οὐδέν· καὶ ἐὰν δὴ λέγωμεν Σίβυλλάν τε καὶ ἄλλους, ὅσοι μαντικῇ χρώμενοι ἐνθέῳ πολλὰ δὴ πολλοῖς προλέγοντες εἰς τὸ μέλλον ὤρθωσαν, μηκύνοιμεν ἂν δῆλα παντὶ λέγοντες. τόδε μὴ ἄξιον ἐπιμαρτύρασθαι, ὅτι καὶ τῶν παλαιῶν οἱ τὰ ὀνόματα τιθέμενοι οὐκ αἰσχρὸν ἡγοῦντο οὐδὲ ὄνειδος μανίαν· οὐ γὰρ ἂν τῇ καλλίστῃ τέχνῃ, ᾗ τὸ μέλλον κρίνεται, αὐτὸ τοῦτο τοὔνομα ἐμπλέκοντες μανικὴν ἐκάλεσαν. ἀλλ’\,ὡς καλοῦ ὄντος ὅταν θείᾳ μοίρᾳ γίγνηται, οὕτω νομίσαντες ἔθεντο, οἱ δὲ νῦν ἀπειροκάλως τὸ ταῦ ἐπεμβάλλοντες μαντικὴν ἐκάλεσαν. ἐπεὶ καὶ τήν γε τῶν ἐμφρόνων ζήτησιν τοῦ μέλλοντος, διά τε ὀρνίθων ποιουμένων καὶ τῶν ἄλλων σημείων, ἅτ’\,ἐκ διανοίας ποριζομένων ἀνθρωπίνῃ οἰήσει νοῦν τε καὶ ἱστορίαν, οἰονοϊστικὴν ἐπωνόμασαν, ἣν νῦν οἰωνιστικὴν τῷ ω σεμνύνοντες οἱ νεοὶ καλοῦσιν· ὅσῳ δὴ οὖν τελεώτερον καὶ ἐντιμότερον μαντικὴ οἰωνιστικῆς τό τε ὄνομα τοῦ ὀνόματος ἔργον τ’\,ἔργου, τόσῳ κάλλιον μαρτυροῦσιν οἱ παλαιοὶ μανίαν σωφροσύνης τὴν ἐκ θεοῦ τῆς παρ’\,ἀνθρώπων γιγνομένης.

      Ἀλλὰ μὴν νόσων γε καὶ πόνων τῶν μεγίστων, ἃ δὴ παλαιῶν ἐκ μηνιμάτων ποθὲν ἔν τισι τῶν γενῶν, ἡ μανία ἐγγενομένη καὶ προφητεύσασα οἷς ἔδει ἀπαλλαγὴν ηὕρετο, καταφυγοῦσα πρὸς θεῶν εὐχάς τε καὶ λατρείας· ὅθεν δὴ καθαρμῶν τε καὶ τελετῶν τυχοῦσα ἐξάντη ἐποίησε τὸν ἑαυτῆς ἔχοντα πρός τε τὸν παρόντα καὶ τὸν ἔπειτα χρόνον, λύσιν τῷ ὀρθῶς μανέντι τε καὶ κατασχομένῳ τῶν παρόντων κακῶν εὑρομένη.
  \end{document}
```

Comment: No, it apparently doesn't. I see no difference between the output with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, apart from the missing hyphenation. Support for ancient Greek hyphenation has recently changed, so I guess it's a problem with the incomplete port of `polyglossia` to LuaLaTeX or, possibly, with the hyphenation pattern loading in LuaLaTeX.

Comment: If I do `lualatex -recorder test`, I find that LuaTeX loads `hyph-el-polyton.pat.txt` instead of the expected `hyph-grc.pat.txt` file.

Comment: After further research it seems that the wrong language name is passed when `language.dat.lua` is examined.

Comment: Is there a way to tell lualatex to load the right file? I can see different `*hyph-el-polyton*` and `hyph-grc*` files? In my `language.dat.lua` it says: `-- from hyphen-ancientgreek:['ancientgreek'] = {loader = 'loadhyph-grc.tex', lefthyphenmin = 1, righthyphenmin = 1, synonyms = {  }, patterns = 'hyph-grc.pat.txt', hyphenation = '', },`

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112905/12277

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyphenation seems to work fine with babel (but I don't understand greek):

```
\documentclass[paper=a6]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showhyphens}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{GFS Porson}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}
  \begin{document}
\greekfont      ΣΩ.\quad Οὑτωσὶ τοίνυν, ὦ παῖ καλέ, ἐννόησον, ὡς ὁ μὲν πρότερος ἦν λόγος Φαίδρου τοῦ Πυθοκλέους, Μυρρινουσίου ἀνδρός· ὃν δὲ μέλλω λέγειν Στησιχόρου τοῦ Εὐφήμου, Ἱμεραίου. λεκτέος δὲ ὧδε, ὅτι οὐκ ἔστ’\,ἔτυμος λόγος ὃς ἂν παρόντος ἐραστοῦ τῷ μὴ ἐρῶντι φῇ δεῖν χαρίζεσθαι, διότι δὴ ὁ μὲν μαίνεται, ὁ δὲ σωφρονεῖ. εἰ μὲν γὰρ ἦν ἁπλοῦν τὸ μανίαν κακὸν εἶναι, καλῶς ἂν ἐλέγετο· νῦν δὲ τὰ μέγιστα τῶν ἀγαθῶν ἡμῖν γίγνεται διὰ μανίας θείᾳ μέντοι δόσει διδομένης.

      Ἥ τε γὰρ ἐν ∆ελφοῖς προφῆτις αἵ τ’\,ἐν ∆ωδώνῃ ἱέρειαι μανεῖσαι μὲν πολλὰ δὴ καὶ καλὰ ἰδίᾳ τε καὶ δημοσίᾳ τὴν Ἑλλάδα ἠργάσαντο, σωφρονοῦσαι δὲ βραχέα ἢ οὐδέν· καὶ ἐὰν δὴ λέγωμεν Σίβυλλάν τε καὶ ἄλλους, ὅσοι μαντικῇ χρώμενοι ἐνθέῳ πολλὰ δὴ πολλοῖς προλέγοντες εἰς τὸ μέλλον ὤρθωσαν, μηκύνοιμεν ἂν δῆλα παντὶ λέγοντες. τόδε μὴ ἄξιον ἐπιμαρτύρασθαι, ὅτι καὶ τῶν παλαιῶν οἱ τὰ ὀνόματα τιθέμενοι οὐκ αἰσχρὸν ἡγοῦντο οὐδὲ ὄνειδος μανίαν· οὐ γὰρ ἂν τῇ καλλίστῃ τέχνῃ, ᾗ τὸ μέλλον κρίνεται, αὐτὸ τοῦτο τοὔνομα ἐμπλέκοντες μανικὴν ἐκάλεσαν. ἀλλ’\,ὡς καλοῦ ὄντος ὅταν θείᾳ μοίρᾳ γίγνηται, οὕτω νομίσαντες ἔθεντο, οἱ δὲ νῦν ἀπειροκάλως τὸ ταῦ ἐπεμβάλλοντες μαντικὴν ἐκάλεσαν. ἐπεὶ καὶ τήν γε τῶν ἐμφρόνων ζήτησιν τοῦ μέλλοντος, διά τε ὀρνίθων ποιουμένων καὶ τῶν ἄλλων σημείων, ἅτ’\,ἐκ διανοίας ποριζομένων ἀνθρωπίνῃ οἰήσει νοῦν τε καὶ ἱστορίαν, οἰονοϊστικὴν ἐπωνόμασαν, ἣν νῦν οἰωνιστικὴν τῷ ω σεμνύνοντες οἱ νεοὶ καλοῦσιν· ὅσῳ δὴ οὖν τελεώτερον καὶ ἐντιμότερον μαντικὴ οἰωνιστικῆς τό τε ὄνομα τοῦ ὀνόματος ἔργον τ’\,ἔργου, τόσῳ κάλλιον μαρτυροῦσιν οἱ παλαιοὶ μανίαν σωφροσύνης τὴν ἐκ θεοῦ τῆς παρ’\,ἀνθρώπων γιγνομένης.

      Ἀλλὰ μὴν νόσων γε καὶ πόνων τῶν μεγίστων, ἃ δὴ παλαιῶν ἐκ μηνιμάτων ποθὲν ἔν τισι τῶν γενῶν, ἡ μανία ἐγγενομένη καὶ προφητεύσασα οἷς ἔδει ἀπαλλαγὴν ηὕρετο, καταφυγοῦσα πρὸς θεῶν εὐχάς τε καὶ λατρείας· ὅθεν δὴ καθαρμῶν τε καὶ τελετῶν τυχοῦσα ἐξάντη ἐποίησε τὸν ἑαυτῆς ἔχοντα πρός τε τὸν παρόντα καὶ τὸν ἔπειτα χρόνον, λύσιν τῷ ὀρθῶς μανέντι τε καὶ κατασχομένῳ τῶν παρόντων κακῶν εὑρομένη.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does. The more I was wondering.

Comment: The loaded hyphenation patterns are wrong, though: `hyph-el-polyton.pat.txt` instead of `hyph-grc.pat.txt`

Comment: @egreg: Yes, it looks as if luatex-hyphen doesn't get the correct languagename. On the whole I think it is a babel-greek bug (and I'm not sure if is a good idea to setup ancient/plutoniko as "language attribute", as it means that you can't mix the greek variants in a document.)

Comment: The hyphenation doesn't change, as far as I can see, if I omit `\languageattribute{greek}{ancient}`. The f[ra]cking problem is that it allows hyphenation after single vowels at the beginning of a word. I can't prevent it from doing so by writing `lefthyphenmin=4` and `righthyphenmin=4`.

Comment: @AlexanderWittmann: You can try `\hyphenrules{ancientgreek}` before the greek text. This seems to load the other patterns. But imho you should also make a bug report to the babel-greek maintainer. `\lefthyphenmin=4` should work too, but you must issue it when the language is active (e.g. after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: So, babel + lualatex work in Greek-only texts, but not if I combine it with, say, german.