# How is the support for polyglossia in LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, polyglossia

[The `polyglossia` manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) states that

> Polyglossia is a package for facilitating multilingual typesetting with XeLaTeX and
>   (at an early stage) LuaLaTeX.

However, I could not find any words about the consequences of its being "at an early stage". How much of it is supported in LuaLaTeX, and how stable is it? Should I feel "safe" when publishing a book using LuaLaTeX?

**Note:** The book I am going to publish is in **Danish** (but with some Greek text occasionally); however, for the sake of keeping the answers useful for everyone, I would suggest that people focus on the general question.

Comment: Is there anything specific why you don't want to use the babel package instead?

Comment: I thought babel did not work in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: babel works great in LuaLaTeX and is the recommended solution. See also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87155/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-xelatex-and-lualatex).

Comment: Also if the document includes some Greek?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: @JuriRobl Actually no, if you a have look into the lualatex manual, you will see that they recommend to use polyglossia. I use this combination for all my documents and never had any problems. Poly b loss ja uses fontspec which one will always load when using lualatex, it is more lightweight and the commands for switching languages are more convenient

Comment: @MaxNoe They don't seem to prefer one or the other, except in Sec. 2.1. In any case it shouldn't be hard to switch if one encounters problems with one of them. I had some problems with polyglossia, but that was some time (and LuaLaTeX versions) ago.

Comment: @Gaussler [You might actually have problems with Greek](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219025/does-polyglossia-with-lualatex-hyphenate-greek-text), if that isn't patched already.

Comment: Seems not to be the case. I got no hyphenations with lualatex .

Comment: @MaxNoe What seems not to be the case? That it works?

Comment: I referred to the possibility of a patch

Comment: Arabic is still a problem with a `polyglossia` and `LuaLaTeX` combination.

Comment: Several users suggest here to use babel instead. This could help to decide: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482396/decide-between-polyglossia-and-babel-for-lualatex-in-2019