# Latin text not hyphenated at all with LuaLaTeX and polyglossia

Tags: luatex, languages, hyphenation, polyglossia

I recently noticed that there are numerous under- and overfull hboxes in the document I'm working on. Further inspection revealed that such problems almost always arose when there was Latin text involved; seemingly, LaTeX doesn't see any hyphenation points, so it can't break lines and paragraphs end up looking ugly.

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}

\begin{document}
\showhyphens{\textenglish{amusing}}
\showhyphens{\textlatin{instigare}}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this code with LuaLaTeX yields a log file; here are the relevant fragments:

> [][] \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 amus-ing 
>   [][] \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 instigare

Omitting the variant option of the Latin language (`variant=classic`) does not change the result.

I have left out some things, such as the font setup, which, from what I have seen in my investigations, is involved in the matter (don't know why, though). However, I hope the example provided is enough — if it isn't, please, ask. For the record, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219025/does-polyglossia-with-lualatex-hyphenate-greek-text) seems somewhat relevant, although I haven't been able to extrapolate the results to my case.

EDIT: This is another MWE aimed at XeLaTeX, under which -as pointed out by egreg- it seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}

\begin{document}
\showhyphens{\textenglish{amusing}}
\showhyphens{\textlatin{instigare}}
\end{document}
```

In the corresponding log file:

> \EU1/lmr/m/n/10 amus-ing 
>   []\EU1/lmr/m/n/10 in-sti-gare

Comment: A bug in the loading of the hyphenation patterns with LuaLaTeX? I get the expected result with XeLaTeX (using the `\showhyphens` version provided by `xltxtra`).

Comment: I added `\setotherlanguage{italian}` just for a check; if I run with `lualatex -recorder`, I see that `hyph-it.pat.txt` is read in, but there's no entry for the corresponding file for Latin. The same if I call Latin without the `variant=classic` option.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. It indeed works with XeLaTeX. I added a modified MWE following your comment.

Comment: @egreg These are, I believe, the relevant files in the polyglossia package: [gloss-latin.ldf](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-latin.ldf) and [gloss-italian.ldf](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/master/tex/gloss-italian.ldf). I barely understand them, but at the top of the Latin one, there are a couple of lines commented out which seem relevant to the matter.

Comment: Very interesting finding! This seems really a bug in `gloss-latin.ldf`. Up to now I'm able to get hyphenation with `\setotherlanguage{latin}` (no `variant=classic` option). Stay tuned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a bug in `gloss-latin.ldf` that doesn't advertise the pattern file name for LuaLaTeX.

Workaround: do it yourself.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=classic]{latin}
\setotherlanguage{italian}

\makeatletter
\def\latin@language{%
  \language=\l@classiclatin
  \xpg@set@language@luatex@ii{classiclatin}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\message{\the\language -->}\showhyphens{amusing}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{latin}
\message{\the\language -->}\showhyphens{instigare}
\end{otherlanguage*}

\begin{otherlanguage*}{italian}
\message{\the\language -->}\showhyphens{istigare}
\end{otherlanguage*}
\end{document}
```

Here's the output on the terminal; note that 54 is exactly the number assigned to the classic Latin hyphenation patterns.

```
0-->
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--16
[][] \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 amus-ing
 54-->
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--19
[][] \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 in-sti-gare
 51-->
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 23--23
[][] \EU2/lmr/m/n/10 isti-ga-re
```

Answer (score 8):

I have fixed the bug in Polyglossia with [this commit](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/commit/21832c8) and will make an upload to CTAN shortly.  Many thanks to Enrico for investigating and suggesting a workaround.

Comment: Working here (TL '15, polyglossia v1.40.1) when I set `"variant=classic"`, but still broken for `="modern"` and `="medieval"` or for not setting a variant at all.

Comment: @Florian I’ve just pushed a fix to master on GitHub if you want to try it out; otherwise I’ll make an upload to CTAN in the next few days anyway.