# hyphenation with languages in transliteration // forced hyphenation?

Tags: luatex, babel, hyphenation, book-design

I am typesetting (lualatex) a document in a couple of languages. The main language is English. If I use other languages I usually use commands such as `\foreigntextquote{french}{text}` and `\foreignlanguage{german}{text}`, hoping that this sorts out a couple of things and in particular hyphenation. I could also manage, [with some help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112905/12277), the hyphenation of Ancient Greek (`polutonikogreek`).

My main issue now is that some languages that are not written in the Latin alphabet are sometimes used in transliteration. For example in Arabic, I would sometimes (usually in the main body of the text) write, *yaštariku* instead of يشترك or *al-mutaʿallim* instead of المتعلّم.

But, how can I manage to get these transliterations hyphenated?

They are not a "known" language (at least not in transliteration). I do not know whether there are established rules, and I assume that even if there are that they have not been integrated into `babel`. Sometimes the words even have a dash by themselves (due to the article *al-*), which is a known problem (but there are also some solutions).

But generally, my questions is this: Since I cannot declare in my preamble **all** words I will use in transliteration (the command `\hyphenation{...}` would be too lang; this would just be insane), I would like to know if there is a way to perhaps *randomly* hyphenate those words which `babel` does not know how to hyphenate or an easy way to create a new hyphenation language and declare its rules? Or is there any other recommendation how to hyphenate all these transliterated words?

Without a solution, my document has a number of words that are written into the margins or lines whose inter-word space is too large.

This should actually be a pressing problem for typesetting in all humanities, for publishers tend to use transliteration in their publications. I don't know how the publishers handle that.

Comment: Since you are using luatex, I presume you can define a function to insert discretionaries with the help of some regexps. Also, with luatex it should be possible to create a new language with their corresponding patterns. Sorry for not being more specific - I think in a couple of week I could work those ideas out.

Comment: @JavierBezos : I will see if I can do something along the lines you suggested. If there is anything I can help you with in "working those ideas out" please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is rather crude solution, which just inserts a `\-`
between a vowel and some consonants:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function insdisc (s)
    -- add more letters if necessary
  s = s:gsub( [[([aeiou])([bcfgklmnpqtxz])]] , '%1\\-%2' )
    -- but don't leave a single char alone:
  s = s:gsub( '^(.)\\%-', '%1')
  s = s:gsub( '\\%-(.)$', '%1')
  return s
end
\end{luacode*}

\def\insdisc#1{\directlua{tex.print(insdisc(\luastring{#1}))}}

\begin{document}

\hsize1mm

Text \insdisc{umiq'utzexopab} umiq'utzexopab text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow! what you call "crude" I'd call "simple" or even "elegant". At first, I had problems with `ellipsis` package, but this just led me to no longer use it.

Comment: I just had the issue that `\insdisc` tried to hyphenate other LaTeX commands, e.g., in `\insdisc{blabla \texquote{abcdefg} blabla}` it tried to hyphenate `\textquote` which, of course, resulted in an error message. Any way to keep that from happening?